# Where are Android system media files stored?

Tags: android

Where does Android store system media files? Specifically I'm looking for the system "click" audio file.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This questions is probably more suited for [Android.stackexchange.com](https://android.stackexchange.com/)

incidentally I already asked something very similar on there. See: [Disable system tick sound](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/26091/disable-system-tick-sound/26092)

and for reference the location of that file on my device (T-mobile Sidekick 4g) was

```
/system/media/audio/ui/TW_Touch.ogg
```

note: you'll need a rooted device to get to it.

Comment: I posted on Stack Overflow because I need it for development purposes. Thanks!